# Is there an API on Facebook like Foursquare venues explore?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, foursquare

In Foursquare API, there is the endpoint "explore venues", you give lat and lng filtering by food for example and it returns a list of venues. Is there something like on Facebook? I couldn't find...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With search API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Run this example on Graph API Explorer:

```
search?distance=1000&center=-23.5475381,-46.5684873&type=place
```